# Display most recent logs for every user

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

How to display most recent logs for every user?
        My database tables are user_log_id, username, login_date, logout_date, user_id. Can you please help me with the query? Thank you

Heres my code:

```
 <?php
    $user_query = $conn->query("select * from user_log order by user_log_id DESC ")or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = $user_query->fetch()){
   $id = $row['user_log_id'];
   ?>
   <tr>
   <td><?php echo $row['login_date']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['logout_date']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td>
   </tr>
   <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Please, provide your code, it's important to include what you have tried on your question, besides that, more details are also crucial to help other users to find an answer to your problem, i recommend reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. I just editted my question. Thank you

Comment: This archaic and insecure API was deprecated so long ago, I don't even remember when.

Answer (score 0):

The `MySql` query you used is correct for getting recent logs. But if you need to get only for specific users or only for logged in users, you have to add a `where` clause in the query.

```
select * from user_log where username=".$row['username']." order by user_log_id DESC
```